# Roll two dice java program

Tags: java

I need to write a simple java program "Roll the Dice" with special variables: When the user rolls the dice, the application rolls two dice, displays the results of each, and asks if the user wants to roll again. Write a program that has the Main method and a separate method for the random number generator. Create a 4 integer variables to store two dice, sum of the two dice, and one for the number of times the dice are rolled. One string variable to hold the player’s name and a character variable to hold a ‘y’ or ‘n’. I spend an hours to try make it right but nothing really  works. this what I have so far and I can't do more:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

public class Main {




public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println( "Welcome to the Karol’s Roller Application" );
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice = "y";

    choice = Validator.getString(sc, "Roll the Dice? (y/n): ");

    while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
    {

        choice = Validator.getString(sc, "Roll again? (y/n): ");


        }
    }


 Random randomNumbers = new Random();{

 int dieOne = 0;
 int dieTwo = 0;
 int totals[] = new int[ 13 ];

 for( int index = 0; index < totals.length; index++ ) {
 totals[ index ] = 0;

 for( int roll = 1; roll <=4; roll++ ) {
    dieOne = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    dieTwo = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    totals[ dieOne + dieTwo ]++;}

 System.out.println( "Roll 1" +
         "\n " + dieOne + " " + 
         "\n " + dieTwo + " ");

if (totals[ dieOne + dieTwo ] == 7 )
System.out.println( "Craps!" + "\n" );

else if (totals[ dieOne + dieTwo ] == 2 )
System.out.println( "Snake eyes!" + "\n" );

else if (totals[ dieOne + dieTwo ] == 12 )
System.out.println("Box cars!" + "\n");




}

   }

}
```

Please, if someone can help me to do correct this program that I have some issue with, the result should look more or less like this:

```
Welcome to the "name here" Roller Application

Roll the dice? (y/n): y

Roll 1:
number on dice one
number on dice two

Roll again? (y/n): y

Roll 2:
number on dice one
number on dice two

Roll again? (y/n): y

Roll 3:
number on dice one
number on dice two

Roll again? (y/n): y

Roll 4:
number on dice one
number on dice two
```

Comment: This is not a reasonable indentation pattern, there is an extra bracket so I doubt it will compile, and I expect you wanted the dice rolling stuff to be inside the while loop (or defined in a helper method called from there). If in doubt do one thing at a time and test that it works. The step by step approach to programming is really the way to go.

Comment: Fix your identation in code. It will help you much better finding syntax and some logic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally broken. Consider what does happen when someone does roll snakeseyes:

```
roll1 = 1
roll2 = 1
totals[roll1 + roll2]++; -> totals[2] = 1
```

Then later you do

```
if (totals[roll1 + roll2] == 2) { ...
```

which will never succeed, because rolling snakeeyes will merely incremenent `totals[2]` to `1`, not 2...

You don't need the `totals` array at all:

```
if(roll1 + roll2 == 7) {
  ... craps ...
} else if (roll1 + roll2 == 2) {
   ... snake eyes ...
} else etc....
```

Comment: ok, I fixed the problem with with the totals array's and I can see change. Possible I do not need this fancy way off sum result like "snake eyes" or "craps" just regular totals will be fine. I still can't do the simply thing:

Comment: ok, I fixed the problem with with the totals array's and I can see change. Possible I do not need this fancy way off sum result like "snake eyes" or "craps" just regular totals will be fine. I still can't do the simply thing: "Roll the dice? (y/n): y" for the first roll and "Roll again? (y/n): y" for each another roll. Also when I choose "n" for "no" that does not working. I am searching my textbook back and forth to fond also how to figure out how to make a count of Roll 1, Roll 2,....I am just getting Roll 1 at all the time.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to learn basic programming. Your code simply enters an infinite loop if anything EXCEPT a `y` is entered, and nothing in that loop actually calls your dice rolling code.